# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group linked Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, cocoapods

I have this Pod file

```
use_frameworks!

target 'projectName' do
pod 'moa', '~> 8.0'
pod 'Auk', '~> 7.0'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK', '~> 2.12.0'
end
```

The installation of the cocoapods was error free.
Now, when i run the project i have this error "Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group" an my project have all Products in red.

[image]

Any one can help me? image error

[image]

Comment: show the full error

Comment: ld: framework not found Auk
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: can attach the image

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i put image on edit question

Comment: are you changed the other linker flags, bz the error is not relaetd to pods,

Comment: I do not understand... You can teach me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142168/discussion-between-hidecode-and-anbu-karthik).